# MYSQL Unable to update parent table - Relational Database Design, foreign key constraints and cascading update / delete

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a very simple database design for managing TV shows:

1. Parent table: `tv_shows`. Primary key: `show_id`
2. Child table: `seasons`. Primary key: `season_id`, Foreign key: `show_id`
3. Child table: `episodes`. Primary key: `episode_id`, Foreign key: `season_id`

Table creation SQL:

```
     $sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$table_shows.";
        CREATE TABLE $table_shows (
          show_id int(11) NOT NULL,
          name varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (show_id),
          UNIQUE KEY  show_id_UNIQUE (show_id)
        ) $charset_collate;

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$table_seasons.";
        CREATE TABLE $table_seasons (
          season_id int(10) NOT NULL,
          show_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          name varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (season_id),
          KEY seasons_ibfk_1 (show_id),
          CONSTRAINT  seasons_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY  (show_id) REFERENCES $table_shows (show_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) $charset_collate;

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$table_episodes.";
        CREATE TABLE $table_episodes (
          episode_id int(10) NOT NULL,
          season_id int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
          name varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (episode_id),
          KEY  season_id (season_id),
          CONSTRAINT  episodes_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY  (season_id) REFERENCES $table_seasons (season_id)
        ) $charset_collate;";
```

What I want to happen is if a show was deleted from the `tv_shows` table, then the delete cascades, so the `seasons` and `episodes` are also deleted from their respective tables.

I can insert into these tables fine. But if I try and delete a row from the tv_shows table then I get an SQL error:

`ERROR 1451: 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

So where have I gone wrong with my FK constraints?

Comment: I imagine the on delete cascade works top down so a delete from shows  will delete seasons which then throws an error because episodes is orphaned.

Comment: Try adding an `ON DELETE SET NULL` cascade to the episodes constraint (since `season_id` is nullable)

Comment: 3 syntax errors in your create statements all the same comma(,) is missing after the  name varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL in all cases. I'm not convinced about your design either presumably every show has a season and there are many episodes within every show/season so the table_episodes seems a normalization to far to me.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for pointing out the syntax issue. I'd removed some lines for brevity so this isn't an issue (I will edit though). So would you suggest merging the episodes table into seasons and just working with two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `ON DELETE CASCADE` to the episodes as well.  This ensures that they all follow each other into the bin.

```
CONSTRAINT  episodes_ibfk_1 
    FOREIGN KEY  (season_id) 
    REFERENCES $table_seasons (season_id)   
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```